# Calculating probability of sale from auction data

Tags: time-series, probability, distributions, bayesian, confidence-interval

I have some data representing the last 6 months of closed auction data from a particular website. The data I have includes market value of product, actual sale amount, and date sold. I have about 600 closed auctions worth of data. I represent the sale data as a percentage, saleAmount/Value. So a product worth \$100 sold for $30 is represented as 30%.

I want to come up with an answer to the following question:

There exists a percentage X such that if I were to bid up to X on every item that goes to auction then I will win one auction every Y months with Z degree of confidence. ie - To win an auction every 4 months(Y = 4) then what percentage of the value(X) should I bid up to? And what degree of confidence can I have in this model (Z)?

I sorted just the last 4 months of auctions and took the minimum but that seems to easy and haphazard. If I remove outliers there is a drastic difference.

Im sure theres a more concise way to ask but I dont have the statistical language to really know what Im looking for so sorry in advance.

Any help is greatly appreciated.